# О слове «опечатать»

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, морфемика, корень-слова

Откуда происходит слово "опечатать" и какой у него корень?

Answer (score 2):

• О корне
Из морфемно-орфографического словаря Тихонова:
[опеча́тать](https://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-o.htm) — о/печат/а/ть (**о-** — приставка, **-печат-** — корень, **-а** — суффикс, **-ть** — глагольное окончание).

• О этимологии
Из этимологического словаря Фасмера (печать):
праслав. основа на согласный – *реčаt- (ср. Дильс, там же), – вероятно, от пеку́ (см.), т. е. "орудие для выжигания знака"... Неубедительно сравнение с лтш. pęka "лапа, ступня, большой гриб" и греч. πεσσόν "игральная доска", πεσσός "игральная кость", вопреки Зубатому... греч. слова следует связывать с др.-инд. рāc̨ī "камень", рāс̨аs "кубик, игральная кость", арм. уеsаn "точильный камень" (*реḱеnā)... Абсолютно невероятно предположение о заимствовании из тюрк. bitik "буква, письмо", вопреки Микколе...

В этимологическом словаре Семенова ([печать](https://gufo.me/dict/semenov/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)):

> Древнерусское – печать (знак).
> В русском языке слово «печать» широкое употребление получило в XIII в.
> Печатью называли знак, вырезанный из дерева, металла или камня для оставления оттисков. Еще раньше так называли знаки, выжженные на поверхности камня или дерева, поэтому предполагают родство этого слова с глаголом «печь».
> Производные: печатать, отпечаток, печатный.

• О значении (печать → печатать → опечатать)
[опечатать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/121390/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), *что*
Наложить государственную печать на что-либо для сохранения в неприкосновенности; запечатать. *Опечатать квартиру. Опечатать здание, помещение. Опечатать дом, сейф*. **//** Наложить печать при аресте, описи имущества и т. п. *Опечатать имущество. Опечатать склад, магазины. Опечатать товары. Опечатать бумаги.*

• Примеры
*Без десяти минут одиннадцать она должна была принять от них всю секретную документацию в большой несгораемый шкаф и **опечатать дверь** лаборатории* (Александр Солженицын. В круге первом);
*Теперь здесь имущество, подлежащее описи, а не вещи вашего друга. **Все следует опечатать**. И так не по правилам...* (Валериан Скворцов. Сингапурский квартет).

Comment: Ой-ёй! Что-то случилось, *Luan*? *Что* это Вас вдруг не устроило, с чем связана "отметательность" уже принятого ответа? Объясните, пожалуйста.