# Каким способом образован глагол "опечатать?

Tags: словообразование

Это вопрос о **словообразовательном анализе** глагола "опечатать".

***Словообразовательный разбор** — это анализ слова, который помогает узнать, производное оно или непроизводное, а также с помощью чего и от какого слова с тем же корнем оно образовалось.*

И вот решение этого вопроса вызывает затруднение: от глагола ***"печатать"*** (префиксальный способ) или от существительного ***"печать"*** (префиксально-суффиксальный способ).

Какое значение имеет **приставка *О*** в этих случаях? Какое значение **у глагола и у существительного** (оба слова многозначные)?

Спасибо.

О морфемном разборе глагола "опечатать" [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473469/О-слове-опечатать](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473469/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)